# Short CIrcuit in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

How to make short circuit in where clause, e.g:

```
select 1 where 1=2 AND 1/0=0
```

In the above example `1/0=0` condition should not be evaluate as the first condition is false.

Answer (score 6):

Just like ypercube commented, Sql Server doesn't adhere to similar a boolean evaluation as, say, Java or C#. There are [lots](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/25/How-SQL-Server-short-circuits-WHERE-condition-evaluation.aspx/) of [articles](https://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bartd/dont-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case), but facts are a bit hard to find.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> The order of evaluation of logical operators can vary depending on
> choices made by the query optimizer.

This behavior is caused by the fact that SQL is a declarative language. In such a language one describes the desired output, not the steps how to build the output. It is up to the RDBMS how to build the output. This often is counter-intuitive to programmers used to procedural and OOP approach, in which one tells explicitly step-by-step what the application should do.

If you got queries that mis-behave with boolean logic evaluation order assumption, I'm afraid you got to re-write those.